# Error during docker installation on windows server 2016

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

I am trying to install docker on windows server 2016 with the following commands:

```
Install-WindowsFeature containers
Restart-Computer -Force
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
set-executionpolicy unrestricted
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
```

Getting the following error with the last command

```
PS C:\Users\win> Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
WARNING: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\Temp\2\DockerMsftProvider\DockerDefault_DockerSearchIndex.json' because it does not exist.
WARNING: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'downloadURL' because it is an empty string.
WARNING: The property 'AbsoluteUri' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
WARNING: The property 'RequestMessage' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'docker'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

I tried using PowerShell and PowerShell ISE as administrator but I get the same error
This is the version of windows server that I am using;

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
```

I also found these commands in the microsoft documentation

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/Main/helpful_tools/Install-ContainerdRuntime/install-containerd-runtime.ps1" -o install-containerd-runtime.ps1
.\install-containerd-runtime.ps1
```

But I get that it does not recognize the tar.exe command and I have not been able to install tar on the version of windows server that I have

```
The term 'tar.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
```